# Interaction plot

Tags: regression, interaction

Not an expert here, working on a paper under review. We have a multiple regression model with an interaction effect. The effect is statistically significant (p<.01) and the plot looks similar to the example below. Slope of the high line is positive & significant (p<.01) and the slope of the low line is negative and significant (p<.05). Overall, plenty of support for our arguments as these all correspond to the hypothesized relationships.

Here is my question: is there a way to test if the end points of the two lines are different from each other (see green circles). A colleague suggests that there is a simple t-test, but I cannot find how to do it. Would greatly help in the review process.

Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: Are there further factors or explanatory variables in the model? If not, you could run a standard two-sample t-test, comparing the samples corresponding to the two end points, i.e., Low/Low vs. Low/High.

Comment: Thanks for the response, there are other variables in the model.

Comment: if we call the covariate on the x axis X1 and the covariate you represented with colors (red/black) as X2, then you just need to refer to the regression results and check the significance of the coefficient on X2.

Comment: Thank you PedroSebe, would a significant coefficient of X2 mean that there is a significant difference between the ends? Which model would I use to interpret this, with or without the interaction effect?

Comment: Please provide more information about the nature of your variables. Are they continuous or categorical? It looks like the x-axis represents values of a continuous variable and the two separate lines represent the levels of a categorical variable, but it's hard to tell for sure. The correct answer depends on those details. in particular, if the x-axis represents a continuous predictor, what particular value do you want to call "low" for your analysis? Also, be warned that estimates near endpoints of continuous predictor ranges are necessarily less precise than those near the middle.

Comment: Thanks for your comment EdM. They are both continuous variables. The high and the low lines are cases of the continuous variable that are +/- 1 std. deviation away from the mean. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite a simple t-test, because if you're doing it yourself you need to do some additional calculations to find the correct standard error to use.

First, you need to specify exactly which sets of values of the two predictors that you want to compare. It seems, from the graphs and the comment stating that these are both continuous predictors, that you want to hold the predictor shown along the x-axis at a value 1 SD below its mean (we'll call that $x_{low}$), and see whether the outcome (we'll call it $y$) differs significantly between the situations with the other predictor (we'll call it $z$) at 1 SD either below ($z_{low}$) or above ($z_{high}$) its mean.

Second, write out the equations for the linear predictor in the 2 cases:

$$y_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_x x_{low} + \beta_z z_{low} + \beta_{xz} x_{low}z_{low}$$

and

$$y_2 = \beta_0 + \beta_x x_{low} + \beta_z z_{high} + \beta_{xz} x_{low}z_{high}$$

The difference $y_2 - y_1$ is thus:

$$y_2 - y_1 = \beta_z (z_{high} - z_{low}) + \beta_{xz} x_{low} (z_{high} - z_{low}) = (z_{high} - z_{low})(\beta_z + \beta_{xz} x_{low})$$

To test whether the difference is significantly different from 0, you need to know the standard error of that particular linear combination of the regression coefficients $\beta_z$ and the interaction coefficient $\beta_{xz}$. For that, you need to retrieve the variances of the estimates of those two coefficients, and the covariance between those estimates, from the variance-covariance matrix that is often hidden from immediate view but is an integral part of a linear regression. Then apply the formula for the [variance of a weighted sum of correlated variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Weighted_sum_of_variables) to get the estimated variance of the difference between the linear predictors, take the square root to get the standard error, and perform your t-test on that.

Most statistical software will provide a way to do this for you. It's important, however, to know what's going on.